# Vapor3 crash when I use fluent with SQLite

Tags: swift, server-side, vapor

I am learning how to make server-side by Vapor,but I got an error which I don't know why.
[image]

It will crash after "Build Success" showed.I am using Vapor 3.0.0-beta.0 by the way.

[image]
[image]

you can download the project code from [github]:https://github.com/RockyAo/ServerSide/tree/master/JSONPoll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vapor 3 beta is currently a little unstable, so make sure you have the latest builds with `swift package update` and try again (note that it now requires Swift 4.1)